# No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts - Postgresql (IF function)

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I tried to run the below query:

```
SELECT account_no, month_id, IF (product_category = 'Services', 'ServicesMarketing', product_category) AS product_category, revenue  
FROM public.revenue_raw_data
```

Error I got:

> ```
> ERROR:  function if(boolean, unknown, character) does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT account_no, month_id, IF (product_category = 'Service...
>                                      ^
> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. 
> You might need to add explicit type casts.
> SQL state: 42883
> Character: 30
> ```

My Data:

[image: view of how my data looks like]

Answer (score 4):

There is no `IF()` function in SQL (or in Postgres).

In Postgres (and standard SQL) you would use a CASE expression

```
SELECT account_no, month_id, 
       case 
         when product_category = 'Services'
              then 'ServicesMarketing'
         else product_category
       end AS product_category, 
       revenue 
FROM public.revenue_raw_data
```

(Note that I am just *guessing* what you think that `if()` should do)

Comment: Oooh great! I tried the CASE expression and it worked. Thanks